# Guidance on solving a recurrence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I am trying to solve the following recurrence:

$T(1) = 2$, and for all $n\ge2$, $T(n) = T(n-1) + n - 1$

By using repeated substitutions, I was able to discern the following formula:

$$T(n)=T(n-i) + ni + \sum_{j=1}^ij$$

I am trying to prove, by induction, that this is a good guess for a formula. However, I am getting hung up trying to prove it.

So far I have the following:

$$T(n)=T(n-i) + ni + \sum_{j=1}^ij$$
$$=T(n-(i-1)) + n(i-1) + \sum_{j=1}^{i-1}j$$
$$=T(n-i)+n-(i+1)+n(i-1) + \sum_{j=1}^{i-1}j$$

After this step I am totally lost, and I am not even sure if what I have done so far is even correct. Most of the induction proofs I have done have just been summations, so I am not very skilled at proving recurrences yet. Any help in pointing me in the right direction or showing me where I am mistaken is greatly appreciated.

**Edit**
I think my main issue (at least from what I can tell) is not knowing what to use for the inductive step. I am trying to prove $T(n)=T(n-i) + ni + \sum_{j=1}^ij$ by induction, which holds when $i=1$. After this, I am confused about how to approach the inductive step. Everything I try, I cannot simplify or I am just making a mistake somewhere. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the recurrence until you hit the bottom at argument 1:
$$
T(n) = T(1) + \sum_{k=n-1}^1 k = 2 + \frac{(n-1)n}{2} =: A(n)
$$
For a proof we first check $n=1$, thus if the initial condition is fulfilled:
$$
A(1) = 2 + \frac{0\times 1}{2} = 2 = T(1)
$$
If $A(n) = T(n)$ for $n$, then
$$
A(n+1) = 2 + \frac{(n+1-1)(n+1)}{2}
= 2 + \frac{n(n-1)}{2} + \frac{2n}{2}
= T(n) + n = T(n+1)
$$
By the principle of induction we deduce $A(n) = T(n)$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Using the original recurrence of $T(n) = T(n-1) + n - 1$ I get the following answers when $1\le{n}\le{5}$:2,3,5,8,12. I also get these answers with my discerned formula above once I simplify it by setting $i=n-1$. So, I am trying to prove this discerned formula. Using your formula of $2 + (n-1)n/2$ I do not get these same answers when trying to verify. Perhaps I am making a mistake. I am not sure. After I prove the base case for my discerned formula, I am lost.

Comment: Never mind, I see that I made an error. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The first time you apply the recurrence, you are adding $n-1$. Then you recurse again and add $n-2$. This goes all the way down until finally you add $1$ for $T(2)$ and then add 2 for $T(1)$ for the initial condition. So you want to compute $T(n) = 2 + \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} j$. This is a standard summation with a simple formula, you can just look up "sum of consecutive integers".

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I know it is $n(n+1)/2$, but I am trying to prove, using induction, that the formula I guess was correct. I did simplify the formula I guessed by setting $i = n-1$, and verified my answers. However, I still having been unable to finish the induction proof for the formula I was able to discern from repeated substitutions method.

Comment: That formula looks close but I don't think it's correct. I believe it should be $2 + {n \choose 2}$. As for how to prove it by induction, just expand the formula you get for $T(n)$ (assumed correct by inductive hypothesis) and then add $n$ to get the formula for $T(n+1)$, and then simplify and show that it is equal to $2 + {{n+1} \choose 2}$.

Comment: In my textbook, in the examples, they do not put the 2 or whatever the base case is into the formula they have discerned from substitutions at first. They always seem to discern a guess first, then prove this guess by induction, and then finally simplify using what they know about the base case. So, I am having trouble following some of the explanations above, because it is not what I am used to seeing